# No Current Class showing in Menu for Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, menus

I have Created Custom Post Types

"NightLife" "Event" "DLStore"

I have added them to Secondary Nav Menu. They show up but when i select the page it does not show any active/current class unlike other Pages like Home or Contact etc.

How can i add a Current Class to this in the Menu.

I have tried all the suggested methods here under similar questions. But couldn't Fix it.

AnyBody Help.

My Menu is Secondary Menu.

Comment: in wordpress  .current_menu_item  is the  defoult class with  the  active menu available  every time  have you check that ?

Comment: yes, you can see my site here http://natpix.in/spirits

Comment: check Home and Order Berevrages show current class, othere Nightclubs, Events , DLStore doesnt show

Comment: yes  here  try to use this class  .cat-item.current-cat > a

Comment: sorry  use  this one    ( .cat-item.cat-item.current-cat > a  )

Comment: What should i do to use the above line

Comment: .cat-item.cat-item.current-cat > a  { color:green !important}   add  this class to your style.css and check

Comment: no didnt work that style

Comment: _How_ have you exactly added archives to menu? If you simply created custom links to archives WP wouldn't know to associate them with CPT posts.

Comment: I created custom post type called nightclubs, dlstore. and created associated page called Nightclubs, DLStore. which i added into the menu. Basically in the menu its just a page item